# How to re-implement Ui_MainWindow generated by Qt

Tags: python, qt, class, pyside

I've created a interface in Qt as .ui file and then converted it to a python file. Then, I wanted to add some functionality to the components such as radio button, etc. For doing so, I tried to re-implement the class from Qt and add my events. But it gives the following error:

```
self.radioButton_2.toggled.connect(self.radioButton2Clicked)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

My first question is whether this is the correct/proper way to deal with classes generated by Qt? And second, why do I get the error?

My code is here:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from InterfaceClass_Test01 import Ui_MainWindow

class MainInterface(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainInterface, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        super(MainInterface, self).setupUi(parent, MainWindow)

        self.radioButton.toggled.connect(self.radioButtonClicked)
        self.radioButton_2.toggled.connect(self.radioButton2Clicked)
        self.radioButton_3.toggled.connect(self.radioButton3Clicked)

    def radioButton3Clicked(self, enabled):
        pass

    def radioButton2Clicked(self, enabled):
        pass

    def radioButtonClicked(self, enabled):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated files are a little unintuitive. The UI class is just a simple wrapper, and is not a sub-class of your top-level widget from Qt Designer (as you might expect).

Instead, the UI class has a `setupUi` method that takes an instance of your top-level class. This method will add all the  widgets from Qt Designer and make them attributes of the passed in instance (which would normally be `self`). The attribute names are taken from the `objectName` property in Qt Designer. It is a good idea to reset the default names given by Qt to more readable ones so that they are easy to refer to later. (And don't forget to re-generate the UI module after you've made your changes!)

The module that imports the UI should end up looking like this:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from InterfaceClass_Test01 import Ui_MainWindow

class MainInterface(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainInterface, self).__init__(parent)
        # inherited from Ui_MainWindow
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.radioButton.toggled.connect(self.radioButtonClicked)
        self.radioButton_2.toggled.connect(self.radioButton2Clicked)
        self.radioButton_3.toggled.connect(self.radioButton3Clicked)

    def radioButton3Clicked(self, enabled):
        pass

    def radioButton2Clicked(self, enabled):
        pass

    def radioButtonClicked(self, enabled):
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it solved the problem! A question: The MainInterface class has 2 arguments, meaning that it's got 2 parents! So, how can I know which __init__ is called when I run it using the Super method?

Comment: The `MainInterface` class does not have two parents: it inherits from two base-classes. The [super](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) call ensures that the `__init__` of all base-classes (and _their_ base-classes, etc), get called in the right order.